# Prove that $(x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}\right)\ge9,$ if $x,y >0.$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

If $x,y>0$,
considering $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}\right)^2$ prove that $(x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}\right)\ge9$.

Comment: What have you tried? At the moment this looks like a homework problem, and without your own attempts this question is not likely to be well-received.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the problem, it is the way it works. Do we assume something about $x,y$? What about $x=1$, and $y=-4$?

Comment: I am not sure that the proposition is true.  Try $x = 0.01, y = 0.04$

Comment: Think [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Comment: C-S: $$(x+y)(1/x+4/y)\geq(1+\sqrt4)^2=9$$

Comment: I've tried use AM-GM but I only got LHS >= 8. By expanding (1/√−2/√)^2 I got 1/x +4/y >= 4/(√xy). Then times (x+y) to the both sides, I got (x+y)(1/x +4/y) >= 4(x+y)/(√xy). Because (x+y)>=2√xy, then (x+y)/2√xy>=1, LHS >= 8

Comment: I despise this website and its pretentiousness and its unwillingness to help people. This question has been closed for "lacking details or clarity" when it is a perfectly well-formed question with an precise answer.  Who joins a Q&A site just to hate on the people who ask questions while refusing to give answers?  Go to Yahoo Answres! or Quora, etc. You will actually get help there; you wont here. You will just be censored and shut down at every turn.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum This question was rightfully closed in my opinion since it does not adhere [to this site's etiquette](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/). After all, providing context benefits both the question asker (who might even solve their own problem during elaboration of their own work) and also other people coming across the question

Answer (score 3):

$$(x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}\right)=\frac{y}{x}+4\frac{x}{y}+5
=\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}-2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\right)^2+4+5\ge9$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$F=(x+y)(1/x+4/y)=1+y/x+4x/y+4=5+(y/x+4x/y)\ge 5+4=9~~~(1)$$
It is by AM-GM that $(A+B) \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$, equality holds if $A=B$.
So in (1) equality holds when $y=2x$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y)(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{y}) = \frac{y}{x} + 4\frac{x}{y} + 5$

We wish to show that this value is always at least 9. Thus, we wish to show that the minimum of this function is at least 9.  Since x,y are both positive we can be assured that this is continuous and differentiable.

Lets define $s=\frac{x}{y}$

We wish to minimize $\frac{1}{s} + 4s + 5 = f(s)$

By simple differentiation, we get $f'(s) = 4 - \frac{1}{s^2}$ which we set equal to zero and solve for s.

Thus clearly $s=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ according to the algebra, but because of how we defined s we know that $s=\frac{1}{2}$ is the only true solution.

Plug this value in for $f(s)$. We get $f(\frac{1}{2})=9$.

We know this is an optimum but is it a minimum?

$f''(s) = 2\frac{1}{s^3}$, and $f''(\frac{1}{2})>0$

We can indeed say that $ \frac{y}{x} + 4\frac{x}{y} + 5 \ge 9$